# Is there a way to inherit BuildConfig from a set of plugins to the current application?

Tags: grails, plugins, build

Is there a 'builtin' way to share BuildConfig from plugins to a host application?

We have an application that is using homemade plugins and we need to copy/paste all special configuration (so everyting but dependency) settings from plugins to current app.

This is quite awful and it brings maintenance issue: when plugin A change its config, we need to update all project using this config.

I would like to be able to re-use as much as possible of the build settings from the plugin and just add specific settings (or replacement settings) to the main project BuildConfig.

The kind of properties we would like to share are:

- common grails config block like:

  grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
  grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
  grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
  grails.project.target.level = 1.6
  grails.project.source.level = 1.6
- specific plugin config:

  grails.project.myplugin.config = { specials things }
- some commons properties like dependencies version

In fact we want to have a kind of inheritance in the builconfig, a bit like when you define a parent project in a maven pom file.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of those "special configuration" from plugin? Just wanted to make sure what would the issue be to have those settings directly in the app and not in the plugins.

Comment: @dmahapatro I have updated my question to give some examples. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

In you're MyAppGrailsPlugin.groovy, you need to add a merge config function:

```
    def doWithSpring = {
      mergeConfig(application)
    }

    private void mergeConfig(GrailsApplication app) {
      ConfigObject currentConfig = app.config.grails.fooConfig
      ConfigSlurper slurper = new ConfigSlurper(Environment.getCurrent().getName());
      ConfigObject secondaryConfig = slurper.parse(app.classLoader.loadClass("FooConfig"))

      ConfigObject config = new ConfigObject();
      config.putAll(secondaryConfig.fooConfig.merge(currentConfig))

      app.config.grails.fooConfig = config;
    }

    def onConfigChange = { event ->
       this.mergeConfig(application)
    }
```

reference: http://swestfall.blogspot.ca/2011/08/grails-plugins-and-default-configs.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you could merge the settings in plugin's `BuildConfig` to app's `BuildConfig`, because it will not be available in classpath to copy yet.

Moreover, your "special settings" (if they are not related to build) should be externalized and go to plugin specific `*Config.groovy` which can be easily *amalgamated* to host app by using the below in host app's `Config.groovy`:

```
grails.config.locations = ["classpath:${pluginSpecific}-config.groovy"]
```

Refer [Externalized Configuration](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#configExternalized) for details and [Plugin Config plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/plugin-config) for more.

On the other hand, when behavior like parent object in maven pom is concerned, the approach to manipulate host app's build process from plugin is kind of scary. This has to be driven by host's build configuration and host can be idempotent about plugin's behavior.

Comment: But all this is to share 'Config', not BuildConfig, isn't it ?

Comment: Yes. You cannot share `BuildConfig` using external config or merging them. Therefore, I mentioned move them to Config if the setting is not related to build.

Comment: So in this case I'm sorry but it is not really an answer to my question: 'Is there a way to inherit BuildConfig'

Comment: The answer is in the first line of my answer. AFAIK there is no way.